# The type of Dictionary initializers

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "12", 12 },
            { "13", 13 },
        };
    }

    static object Fifteen()
    {
        //return new object[] { "15", 15 };
        return new {key = "15", value = 15};
    }
}
```

How do I write `Fifteen` so that I can add it to the initializer?

I want this, that compiles:

```
        var a = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "12", 12 },
            { "13", 13 },
            Fifteen()
        };
```

L.E. the compilation error is: `error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'Dictionary<string, int>.Add(string, int)'`

Comment: No can do, initializers don't work that way. There's only one `Add` method on `Dictionary` and it expects exactly two arguments. If there was an overload expecting a `KeyValuePair<string, int>` you could have used that, but there isn't.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, in c#6.0 it became possible to use extension method `Add` with collection initializer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to change your `Fifteen` method so that it returns a `KeyValuePair`, rather than an `object`, so that the callers of the method can access the data you're providing (anonymous types should only be used when they're consumed in the same method that they're created):

```
static KeyValuePair<string, int> Fifteen()
{
    return new KeyValuePair<string, int>("15", 15);
}
```

And then you'll need to add an extension method to `Dictionary` so that it has an `Add` method that accepts a `KeyValuePair` rather than two arguments:

```
public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair)
{
    dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

After which your stated code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: We can go one step further in C# 7 and leverage `ValueTuple`; that way `Fifteen` could be as brief as `static (string, int) Fifteen() => ("15", 15);`.

Comment: Lovely answer and excellent recommendation from @JeroenMostert too. I sort of hate this "magic" syntactic sugar in the case of vanilla `Dictionary` initializers, but it's cool to see the hacks people can come up with towards normalizing the syntax.

Comment: @foxx1337 I wouldn't really call it a hack to have an `Add` method for a dictionary accepting a key value pair.  It's a semantically appropriate operation for the type to have, not an inappropriate method that doesn't make sense conceptually.  Stripping the type naming on the other hand by using a tuple, and just expecting people to know what things mean does start to move you into the area of hacks and magic, as the user of the code has to have information not conveyed in the code itself.

Comment: @Servy: fortunately, nothing prevents us from writing `(string Key, int Value) Fifteen() => ("15", 15);` (or even `(string Key, int Value) Fifteen() => (Key: "15", Value: 15);` if you want to be *really* explicit); the language offers good support for tagging `ValueTuple` members, even though the names are not conceptually part of the type.

Comment: @Servy what I mean here is that the `{ }` construction "covers" a series of `Add()` operations which can't be represented through C#'s type system. Hence the ingenious workaround you proposed. I would have expected the stuff within the innermost braces to be representable as some `CollectionElementAtomTuple` type, and not just be hack-transformed by the compiler into a series of method calls.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. The dictionary initializer is syntactic sugar. So your code

```
var a = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "12", 12 },
    { "13", 13 },
};
```

Is actually translated to something like:

```
var tmp = new Dictionary<string, int>();
tmp.Add("12", 12);
tmp.Add("13", 13};
var a = tmp;
```

So the elements are used as argument for `Add`. Even if `Fifteen()` would return a `KeyValuePair<string,int>` the compiler would still be missing an appropriate `Add` method.

(But as [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216025/5528593) showed, you can provide an extension `Add` method that does the trick)